# how to find the sum of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

while finding sum as follows

```
g.loc[g.index[0], 'sum'] = g[RDM].sum()
```

where RDM is

```
RDM = [f"R_Dist_meas_{i}" for i in range(48)]
```

the error was as follows:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['R_Dist_meas_0', 'R_Dist_meas_1', 'R_Dist_meas_2',\n   .........................'R_Dist_meas_45', 'R_Dist_meas_46', 'R_Dist_meas_47'],\n     dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

the sample dataframe is as follows,it have many other column other than distance(angle,velocity etc..)
The format of dataframe is **A0B0C0  A1B1C1  A2B2C2  A3B3C3 ....... A47B47C47**

```
| R_Dist_meas_0 |R_vel_meas_0 | R_Dist_meas_1 |R_vel_meas_1 | R_Dist_meas_2 |R_vel_meas_2 |--------| R_Dist_meas_47 |R_vel_meas_47 |
|---------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|
|      5        |             |               |             |               |             |
|               |             |               |             |10             |             |
|               |             |               |             |  8            |             |
|   2           |             |   8           |             |               |             |
```

**the sum = 33**

How to solve it?

Comment: What mean are you trying to get ? Simply getting the mean value of a column is trivial in pandas : `df["column_name"].mean()`

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to modify some value in your DataFrame, could you provide more details about what you are actually trying to achieve in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension will go out of bounds if you try to search the dataframe since you only have columns up to R_Dist_meas_2. If you try to use the RDM as header keys you will be looking for columns not rows.

```
sum(g.iloc[:,:2].sum())
```

Excluding the sum outside, this allows you to sum up the rows of each column seperately and then add their totals for the final summation. This should give you the sum you are looking for.

Comment: the dataframe have many other columns.Will it work?

Comment: You can test it out yourself. Just look up how the iloc works, the first : means we are taking all the rows in the column. After the comma it is looking at the columns from 0 to 2 so if you want to add more columns change 2 to whatever number of columns you have. However, be sure to exclude columns that have string rows.

Comment: i have made some changes..The dataframe is in a format like this: A0B0C0  A1B1C1  A2B2C2  A3B3C3